# How to update a text label in the current window

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I need to update win1.title (a label) with new data returned from a JSON response.
I can print on my console win1.title value, but I cannot assign to it new value!

**app.js**

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    layout: 'vertical',
    url: 'win1.js',
    title: 'Loading...',
    artist: '' });


win1.open();

//Fetching data

var jsonData = ''; var pointer = 0;

var url = "http://example.com"; var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {

        jsonData = JSON.parse(this.responseText).response.songs;



        //HERE I NEED TO UPDATE win1.title with title returned by JSON
        /*
           if a print win1.title it works correctly.
             console.log(win1.title);

           but if I try to assign data to win1.title nothing happens, even a error!

        */


        win1.addEventListener('swipe', function(e) {
                        console.log("win1 title:" + win1.title);            win1.title = jsonData[pointer].title;           win1.artist = jsonData[pointer].artist_name;            win1.image = jsonData[pointer].tracks[0].release_image;

                    });

    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
    timeout:20000  /* in milliseconds */ }); xhr.open("GET", url); xhr.send();  // request is actually sent with this statement
```

**win1.js**

```
(function() {

    var win1 = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

    var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
      image:win1.image,
      top: 40
    });

    var title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
      color: 'white',
      font: { fontSize:38 },
      text: win1.title,
      textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
      top: 20,
      width: 'auto', height: 'auto'
    });

    var artist = Ti.UI.createLabel({
      color: 'white',
      font: { fontSize:28 },
      text: win1.artist,
      textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
      top: 30,
      width: 'auto', height: 'auto'
    });


    win1.add(title);
    win1.add(artist);
    win1.add(image);


})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `win1.title = 'some title';` isn't going to do what you think it will in this case.  [Titanium Window objects](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window) have a [title](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-title) property, and depending on whether you build for iOS or Android, you will see this title at the top of a modal window or when the window is in a tabgroup or navgroup.

Your code is updating this title, but you probably aren't seeing it. (Try adding `modal:true` to your `createWindow()` declaration.)  Also, you have set 2 `title` properties, so remove one of them.

To change the label text in the variable named 'title' on win1.js, you can do the following:

In win1.js, add the following:

```
win1.updateTitle = function(newTitle){
    title.text = newTitle;
}
```

Then, back on app.js, go to wherever you want to update the title and do:

```
win1.updateTitle('new title');
```

Also, you should consider using CommonJS with your Titanium projects:

[CommonJS Best Practices](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/Mobile_Best_Practices-section-29004793_MobileBestPractices-ApplicationsshallbemodularandobjectorientedusingCommonJSmodules)

Comment: up-voted for stressing the importance of CommonJS (and therefore good architecture)